# Can't dismiss FBfriendPickerViewController from delegate method

Tags: ios, facebook, delegates

I am using the facebook FBFriendPickerViewController  and want the user to only be able to select one friend and then have it dismiss the view controller. In the FBFriendPickerDelegate, under the selectionDidChange method I am trying to capture what friend they selected and then dismiss the view controller. I can't get it to dismiss, I feel like I have done this type of thing many times before so I feel kind of dumb asking this, but I feel like I have exhausted every variation of this and nothing works.

```
-(void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker{
    self.selectedFriends = friendPicker.selection;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedFriends);
    [friendPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have also tried

```
[[friendPicker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[self.friendPickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[[friendPicker navigationController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a navigation Viewcontroller that you likely pushed, you would want to pop it:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you present the friendpicker controller modally you can dismiss it by using the facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed and the facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed methods of the FBViewControllerDelegate protocol. If you conform to FBFriendPickerDelegate you automatically conform to the first one.